# Get Vertices of a Shape/Body in Box2D

Tags: box2d

Is there a way to do it? I can get only polygon_shape's vertices, but i want circle, box, etc too.

How to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no such thing as a *box* in in Box2D (ironically). The `SetAsBox` method is a convenience function that creates a 4-ary polygon.

A circle does not have vertices, so you cannot get a list of them. A circle is defined by its radius and its position, and those are both accessible.

Edge and loop shapes use the same vertex storage as a polygon.